# Are some statistical moments harder to estimate than others?

Tags: sample, estimators, moments

Statistical moments include the mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, etc. Since we hardly ever have population data and work with finite sample datasets, we often have to rely on estimators of these in order to measure them called sample estimators.

Are certain specific moments harder to estimate than others? For example is skewness always, or more often, harder to estimate than kurtosis? Does difficulty in estimating moments become harder for higher order moments, given that kurtosis is only the 4th moment, while we also might be interested in the 24th moment thereafter? Do some moments become more difficult to estimate when sample size is reduced? How about the difficulty of estimating odd moments as opposed to even moments, do these two families have a difference?

Mainly looking for whatever alternative hypthosis there is that upsets the null hypothesis that all moments are equally difficult to estimate, in other words, that they all fare equally.

Comment: You could look at at the variances of the moments. I could imagine that for certain distributions the variance of moments increases with the moment, which would imply that they are harder to estimate.

Comment: Well, look at the student-t distribution family with the limiting case of the Cauchy distribution (t with 0 degrees of freedom). Only the moments <= DFs even exist (trying to estimate the mean of a Cauchy is ... obviously "a bit" difficult).

Comment: Kurtosis is 4th moment, not 5th.

Comment: what if the variance of a moment increases with more than one moment? does that make it harder to estimate than a moment whose variance increase with only 'the' moment? (not sure if 'the' implies itself)

Comment: The mean is the first moment about zero. The variance is the second moment about the mean. Skewness and kurtosis are (often, I dare say usually) not moments themselves, but rather calculated from the 3rd and 2nd moments about the mean and the 4th and 2nd moments about the mean respectively, but (1) I've seen the 3rd and 4th moments about the mean sometimes called skewness and kurtosis (2) skewness often and kurtosis sometimes are often calculated quite differently, usually from selected quantiles.

Comment: But the discussion starts easily. Powering deviations (from zero or the mean) creates larger and larger numbers if deviations are $>1$ in absolute value and smaller and smaller numbers if deviations are $<1$ in absolute value. As moments have different dimensions, and different units of measurement if the original variable has units of measurement, their numerical values are not directly comparable, but loosely higher moments are harder to estimate well. Whether all moments exist in principle for mathematically defined reference distributions is a related but different question.

Comment: This is a very broad question, which may lead to a spread of answers. **1)** How do you *define* 'harder to estimate'? **2)** Do you wish an answer that works in general, or an answer for specific cases? (I imagine that a general answer is not easy to give, the type of distribution or assumptions about it will matter a lot, for instance symmetric distributions will not have much interesting odd central moments)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus (1) harder to estimate in that, if the true population moment were known/set, the sample estimator obtains that true value of the moment with high accuracy and precision. (2) a general answer, with specific cases (moments) demonstrated as examples. Especially interested in moments of empirical distributions that are universally unique as opposed to well-known distributions

Comment: High accuracy and precision is still not so clear to me.

Comment: if the *i*th true moment $\mu_i$ is 0.1 with an error of 0.02, i would want a sample estimator $\hat{\mu}_i$ to have a value of 0.1 with a confidence of 0.02 too

Comment: A general question might not be so easy. Depending on the distribution (and depending on your definition of difficult) higher moment estimators might be more or less difficult. For some distributions the moments might not even be defined, so how are you gonna express the precision of the moments of the empirical distributions?

Comment: What do you mean by the error (of 0.02) of the $i$th true moment?

Comment: partition ur answer then between 'well-known distribution cases' and 'the empirical case' .  or just select one case to focus on. This isn't the LSAT.

Comment: @develarist This is not the LSAT, but it would still be useful to specify your question more precisely. For me it is extremely broad and in it's current form can not be answered on this Q&A and requires an entire book to be written about it.

Comment: ok give me some time to change the question to focus on the Gaussian first

Comment: BTW, I am not saying that the question is invalid, bit without a focus, for instance a clear definition of 'harder to estimate', it will be hard to answer and create a wide variety of answers that differ based on the interpretation.

Comment: A Gaussian would be a better precision. In that case, if you wish to estimate higher moments then you do this by estimating $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and use them to express the higher moments. The propagation of error will be multiplied in those expressions, but depending on how you measure precision (variance of the estimator, or something else) it will be better or worse.

Comment: 5th and higher moments have no interest if you know that a distribution is Gaussian. The question of sample size allows some precise answers. Estimates of skewness and kurtosis are bounded as a function of sample size to the extent that samples may even deny their own parentage. More at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0204

Comment: A focus on distribution-free estimation of central moments would resolve any ambiguity & be more interesting than a focus on estimation within a particular parametric family, IMHO

Comment: yes that is the case i am more interested in. should i make one question for the Gaussian density's moment estimators, and repeat the same question seperately for the distribution-free moment estimators?

Comment: I'd say so. You're probably already familiar with the sample mean as an estimator of the distribution's mean, & its variance, & with the (de-biased) sample variance as an estimator of the distribution's variance: there's a series of such estimators called *h-statistics*, the variances of which can be calculated.